# Google Places API Not returning events that currently show in Google Now?

Tags: ios, json, google-places-api

Does Google Now events information not come from Google Places API "events" in the returned results?  I am getting results and I have them plotted to my map view.  I also have a log statement so I can look through all of the results.  I am seeing all of the locations, but one in particular shows no events although in google now I am looking at an event for that location.  If anyone can give me some insight that would be great.  If it is helpful, "events" is absent from all returned results. This is the URL I'm using:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%f,%f&radius=5000&types=%@&sensor=true&num=100&key=%@", latitude, longitude, googleType, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
```

I am parsing it with key "results" into an array and then logging the results array

The results are being returned perfectly, just no events.

Comment: What documentation are you using ? I can only see `nearbysearch` at [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests) API reference and it doesn't have `events` parameter.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchResults   Each result within the results array may contain the following fields:
An events[]: array or one or more <event> elements provide information about current events happening at this place. Up to three events are returned for each place, ordered by start time. For information about events, please read Events in the Places API.

Comment: It doesn't have any API like you are using. See, you are using `/search` and there's only `/radarsearch` `/textsearch` and `/nearbysearch`.

Comment: I updated my url above.  I had a typo.  I am using nearbysearch.  I still believe that events should be returned but maybe I am reading it wrong